# FCC vs CENELEC-B band for IoT application using PLC

Tags: frequency, impedance, power-line-communication

I have done some research on the topic but I have not found any conclusive evidence. I want to design a system where I use the existing cabling inside a building to communicate with various IOT devices using PLC.

I need to make a choice between these two frequency bands; the preferred constraint is **distance** and **robustness** (as low noise as possible). Do power lines have a high impedance at higher or low frequencies.

CENELEC-B ranges from *98.44kHz* to *121.88kHz*
and FCC ranges from *154.68kHz* to *487.50kHz*

Any help is apresisted.

---

Bonous question and answer:

For G3 (not prime) how many sub-carriers are CENELEC-B and in the FCC band.

CENELEC-B has *16 sub-carriers* and FCC has *72 sub-carriers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CENELEC-B will allow the signal to transmit further but there is greater noise interference due to this property.

With more research, I have found that the frequency band 150KHz up has regulation to keep noise from PSU (SMPS) as low as possible in order to pass EMC testing. but in the CENELEC-B band, there are no such regulations as that is were SMPS are gently active (between 9k to 100K).

Therefore I have chosen the FCC band, even tho the signal propagation will not be as far.